# Unable To Get The Property Value Of An Object That Comes From An API Call In REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Why I'm unable to access the property value of the Object That comes from an API Call ?

I Have Two Components In The React App, Both Are Given Below.

Here Is First Component Named 'Weather'

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Styles from "./Weather.module.css";
import WeatherCard from "../Weather Card/WeatherCard.component";

const Weather = () => {
  // Initializing State
  //For Location
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("karachi");
  //For Location
  //For Query
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(location);
  //For Query
  //For Weather Data
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState({});

  //For Weather Data

  // Initializing State

  // Calling data through api

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchingData = async () => {
      let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&appid=6a571911f99d7d02c4974a178ff1d933`;

      let responseFromFetch = await fetch(url); // getting obj of promise.

      let data = await responseFromFetch.json(); // getting api/weather data.

      setWeatherData(data); // setting state that comes from api.
    };

    fetchingData(); // calling func that brings the data
  }, [query]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(location);
    setLocation("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={Styles.formContainer}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            className={Styles.inputField}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Know Your City Weather!"
            value={location}
            onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button type="submit" className={Styles.button}>
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <WeatherCard weatherData={weatherData} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Weather;
```

Okay, Now Here is the second Component Named 'WeatherCard'

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Styles from "../Whether/Weather.module.css";

export default class WeatherCard extends Component {
  render() {
    const accessObj = this.props.weatherData;

    console.log(accessObj); // getting whole obj - No error,
    console.log(accessObj.name); // getting the value of the key "name" - No error,       accessObj.name isn't an object
    console.log(accessObj.sys); // getting obj - No error,          accessObj.sys is an object
    console.log(accessObj.sys.country); // Not getting the value of key "country" - Error

    if (accessObj !== "undefined") {
      return (
        <>
          <div className={Styles.wrapper}>
            <div className={Styles.weatherContainer}>
              <div className={Styles.cityContainer}>
                <p className={Styles.city}>{accessObj.name}</p>
              </div>

              <div className={Styles.countryContainer}>
                {/* I want here to use the value of the property... But country is not available here.  */}

                <p className={Styles.country}>{accessObj.sys.country}</p>
              </div>

              <div className={Styles.tempContainer}>
                <p className={Styles.temp}>30 C</p>
              </div>

              <div className={Styles.humidityContainer}>
                <p className={Styles.humidity}>100</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

You Can Also see the error that occur's in the browser. screenshot link is [HERE](https://pasteboard.co/JaucwPE.png) . Unable to attach the screenshot of the error here, because I'm new in this platform! 
[image]

Advance Thanks For The Help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React app: Undefined value after fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605256/react-app-undefined-value-after-fetch)

Comment: u are consoling before undefined check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access an object information that doesn't have anything at first, so it will be `undefined` until your components gets information from the parent. this happends because the request to get information in the main component is still ongoing in the first render.

Adding a condition to console.log in `<WeatherCard>` will likely fix your problem.

```
if(accessObj.sys){ //Will check if the accessObj.sys object is not undefined; if it's not undefined, it will return true and the console.logs will happen.
   console.log(accessObj);
   console.log(accessObj.name); 
   console.log(accessObj.sys);
   console.log(accessObj.sys.country);
}
```

For the rest of the code you did good, because you added a condition to render, which is basically what I put above.

Comment: Thanks Brother, It Worked! Thank You So Much !

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `accessObj !== "undefined"` but the initial value is an empty object (`{}`). The initial value comes from Weather component `weatherData={weatherData}`.
So your condition `if (accessObj !== "undefined")`is always true.
One possible solution is to initialise `weatherData` like this :
`const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState(null);`
And do the check like this :
`if (accessObj) {}`
This condition will be true after you fetched the data and `setWeatherData`

Answer (score 0):

getting too fancy sometimes can lead you to some issues like the one here basically the problem is that your useEffect hook has a void type as it does not returns anything.

```js
...

const fetchingData = () => {
      let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&appid=6a571911f99d7d02c4974a178ff1d933`;

     return fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => myFunctionThatSetsTheState(data)).catch(console.error)
};

useEffect(() => fetchingData(), [query]);

....
```